# Microsoft Remote Desktop is playing both speaker audio and microphone audio through the microphone

Tags: audio, remote-desktop, audio-streaming

I'm using microsoft remote desktop.

I have set [Remote Audio Playback and Remote Audio recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ9Ov.png)

When I connect to the client machine and join a microsoft teams call (or even just use sound recorder) I can hear the audio from my microphone but also the audio that is played back to the host machine so other people in the call can hear their own voices and any other sound I have going on (youtube etc).

The client machine is right next to me so I have tried:

Using the microphone on the client machine: Worked for about 30 minutes then suddenly changed the input device back to 'remote audio' and can no longer get it to work. When connected all I/O devices are replaced by 'Remote Audio' and no longer visible in any device lists.

Editing group policies in various combinations to disable/enable audio directions.

Looking for a USB over RDP tool but they're all $200.

Any solutions?
I'm happy to use either the host microphone or the client microphone as long as the audio doesn't echo and as long as the client audio plays through the host.

Comment: RDP should only forward the audio. Can you get it to work locally with the same settings as in the RDP environment?

Comment: Asking for a recommendation is off-topic here.  Try posting on Software Recommendations.

Comment: *"I can hear the audio from my microphone"* from where are you hearing that? Your own mic audio should never route to your own speakers.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Some headsets support that ability so you don’t end up screaming into the headset, but if you are hearing yourself loud enough, it actually registers that’s just feedback.

Comment: @Ramhound - That would have to be internally routed in the headset itself, or require drivers/control panel to accomplish it [though you'd probably get annoying latency]. It shouldn't be possible as a system default.

Comment: Sorry, bad choice of words. Thats in relation to when I record using 'Sound Recorder' then press play. I can hear my own voice in the recording and the computer audio.

Comment: Are you playing the normal sound over speakers, or are you using your headset's speakers to listen to the computer audio? Just making sure how hard it would be for the microphone to pick up the external sounds.